# Android - Access Camera and Gallery Icons and Lable Programmatically

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery, android-icons

Is there any way of accessing android's default camera and gallery icon and lable Programmatically?

Can it be done by `activity.getPackageManager();`

I know that we can use package names `com.android.camera` and `com.android.gallery` to retrieve App name and Icon but I was wondering will it work on every single device? Are these package names same on every android version?

Is there any better approach?

Comment: They are not. I have some old motorola device with com.motorola.android.camera or something like that.

Comment: You want their ICON? or to open them?

Comment: their ICON and Lables

Answer (score 0):

Camera is easy. Check who will handle [ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) intent. From all candidates, only one will be installed in `/system/app`.

For Gallery, try to find which package answers on `Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)`.